# What happens when the diffusion term in an SDE becomes zero?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Consider this time-homogeneous SDE, in the Ito sense:
$$dX_t= -(X_t-a)\,dt+\sigma(X_t)\,dW_t,$$
where $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion, $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$, $X_0\leq b$ a.s., and $\sigma(b)=0$. That is, the drift term "pulls" linearly towards $a$, and $\sigma$ is arbitrary, but it becomes zero at $b$. Assuming that the existence of solutions is guaranteed, I would like to conclude that $X_t\leq b$ for all $t$, a.s.

Intuitively, it seems to make sense: If $X_{t_1}>b$, by continuity of the solution there exists $t_0$ such that $X_{t_0}=b$; since $\sigma(X_{t_0})=0$, there is no random "motion," only the drift towards $a$, so the solution cannot go beyond $b$.

Is this intuition correct? And if so, how can one prove it formally?

Comment: Welcome to MO. You need to make some assumptions on $\sigma$ I believe. For example, assume $\sigma(x)=1$ unless $x=b$. The stochastic integral will not "see" the value at $b$,. Of course in such case you lose uniqueness, and it is not clear which is "the" solution you talk about.A solution?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. That is indeed a good point. For the case I am interested in, $\sigma$ is continuous and bounded, but it might not be Lipschitz. I will have to check if it satisfies conditions for a comparison theorem, to be able to apply Thomas' solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following a comparison result (eg. Comparison theorem in Revuz-Yor Chap. IX §3), we will show that $X_{t}\leq b$ for all $t\geq 0$. This result requires though the Yamada-Watanabe regularity

$$|\sigma(x)-\sigma(y)|\leq \rho(|x-y|),$$

for $\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{\rho(s)}ds=\infty, \forall \epsilon>0$. (Perhaps weaker regularity is possible, but as noted by [O.Zeitouni](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463870/what-happens-when-the-diffusion-term-in-an-sde-becomes-zero#comment1204459_463870) the $\sigma(x)=1_{x=b}$ is a counterexample). Consider the SDE

$$dY_{t}=\mu(Y_{t})dt+\sigma(Y_{t})dB_{t},Y_{0}=b$$

where $$\mu(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}0&,y\geq b \\(b-a)-(y-a)&,y\leq b  \end{matrix}\right.$$

The $Y_{t}=b$ is a solution for this SDE. So we have $\mu(y)\geq -(y-a)$ and $X_{0}\leq Y_{0}$ and thus we get

$$P[X_{t}\leq Y_{t}=b\text{ for all t }\geq 0]=1$$

Comment: It seems we only have $\mu_Y (x) \geq \mu_X (x)$ whenever $x \leq b$. In order to apply the comparison result, don’t you need $\mu_Y \geq \mu_X$ everywhere?

Comment: yes thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: Seems to work now, nice!

Comment: Very nice and elegant. I will have to verify that, for the case I am considering, $\sigma$ satisfies the conditions for this or some other similar comparison theorem. But, as stated, this fully answers my question.Thank  you!